# In Eclipse, how do I replace a character by a new line?

Tags: eclipse, editor, text-editor, eclipse-3.4

In Eclipse 3.3.2, I would like to replace a character (say ',') by a new line in a file.
What should I write in the "Replace with" box in order to do so ?

EDIT : Many answers seems to be for Eclipse 3.4. Is there a solution for Eclipse 3.3.X ?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Check box 'Regular Expressions' and use '\R' in the 'Replace with' box

It's a new feature introduced with Eclipse 3.4, See [What's New in 3.4](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/whatsnew3.4/eclipse-news-part1.html)

Comment: Check if Eclipse value assistance in the Replace with box offers you \R as a possibility, if it doesn't your Eclipse version doesn't handle it

Comment: I'm on version 3.3.2 and, the assistance doesn't show me that value.

Comment: This has bugged me for years. I can't believe I never took the time to google how to do it (which of course brought me here.)

Comment: You saved my as minimum 15 minutes

Comment: Eclipse.org have stopped hosting that archived release. I found it online here: http://www.helpml.com:8088/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html (click on **Search** in the Table of contents)

Comment: With the `Find/Replace` dialog open and in focus, press `F1` to bring up a context sensitive help popup and then click on the link to `Find/Replace with regular expressions` to see all the supported escape sequences.

Comment: I am using Eclipse 4.25, and as suggested by @user9796835, I have to **search** with the `Regular expression` option **selected** (i.e. ticked) in order to **enable** the `Regular expression` option when I _subsequently_ select the `Replace` option(s).

Answer (score 3):

Check box 'Regular Expressions' and use '\n' in the 'Replace with' box

Comment: Yes, I tried that first but it is not working on my eclipse (3.3.2).

Comment: This worked for netbeans

Answer (score 3):

Like the others said, just use regular expression, but instead of just \r, put \r\n

Answer (score 1):

if the file search is performed with Regular Expressions checkbox checked, then replace all / replace selected will also allow regular expression and will transform \n to a newline in the file(s)

Answer (score 0):

I've just found [an article about that problem](http://www.andyjarrett.co.uk/2006/11/02/eclipse-regex-and-newline-bug/). It seems to be a bug.

There's a workaround which is to copy a new line in clipboard and then paste it inside the "replace" box.

Comment: I don't even understand what the workaround is supposed to be

Comment: You'll have to select the "new line character" by clicking on the last character's line and move the mouse before the first character on the next line. I indeed select something but I'm not able to paste it in the replace box.

Comment: Managed to paste using right click menu, but the replace won't insert newlines.

Comment: invalid link on the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Helios and it works, however I had some issues with replacement... I wanted to place a line break between any of these brackets "><" (to make each new XML tag go to a new line)... first I had to place a chacter between the 2 brackets, for instance /r, after this i checked the "regular expressions" box and replaced the /r with \R, which resulted in the correct linebreak. otherwise, the replace seemed to be greyed out.