# eclipse: adding a new line after find and replace

Tags: eclipse, replace, find, line, break

Wanted to ask, I want to do something like this via eclipse's find and replace function

```
driver........click();
driver........click();
```

after find and replace

```
driver........click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver........click();
```

is this possible? If so, how do i do it? Many thank for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Eclipse very often, but it [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156707/in-eclipse-how-do-i-replace-a-character-by-a-new-line) like Eclipse supports regular expressions in the search and replace feature.

Something like this will probably work:

**Search:** `(driver.*click\(\);)\r?\n(driver.*click\(\);)`

**Replace:** `$1\r\nThread.sleep\(2000\);\r\n$2`

Also, be sure to check the Regular expressions checkbox in the options section before running this search.